# Fail to install curb gem in windows7

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, curb

curb gem fails to install.
I am using following configuration:-

- Windows 7
- Ruby 2
- Rails 4
- gem "bundler 1.3.5"

> C:\RorProjects>gem install curb

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing curb:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    C:\Users\abc>gem install curb
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while.....
    ERROR:  Error installing curb:
            ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Rubyinstaller200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for curl-config... no
checking for main() in -lcurl... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Rubyinstaller200/bin/ruby
        --with-curl-dir
        --without-curl-dir
        --with-curl-include
        --without-curl-include=${curl-dir}/include
        --with-curl-lib
        --without-curl-lib=${curl-dir}/
        --with-curllib
        --without-curllib
extconf.rb:18:in `<main>':   Can't find libcurl or curl/curl.h (RuntimeError)

  Try passing --with-curl-dir or --with-curl-lib and --with-curl-include
  options to extconf.


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Rubyinstaller200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/
curb-0.8.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Rubyinstaller200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/curb-0.8.4/ext/ge
m_make.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing mingw and run the command within it, I haven'T worked on windows for a while but it used to fix my gem install problems back then :

http://www.mingw.org/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the paths to header files and the static library in order to build the extensions. First make sure you have the [ruby devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) installed. Then [download](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) the x86 package (suffixed 'devel', it's the one that includes all the stuff), extract it somewhere and try `gem install curb -- --with-curl-lib=c:/path/to/curl/lib --with-curl-include=c:/path/to/curl/include`.

If this one doesn't work (for me it didn't when I tried to install curb with libcurl 7.32.0 and ruby 2.0), you can try downloading the x86 libcurl package [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyinstaller/4ulo3o1bQOM/discussion), follow the instruction in the first post to extract it, set up the environment and then run `gem install curb -- -with-opt-dir=c:/path/to/libcurl`. This got me curb 0.8.5 at the time of this post.